# "For" VS "in" usage

Tags: meaning-in-context, prepositions, phrase-meaning, grammaticality-in-context, prepositional-phrases

Which preposition is right and which is wrong?

1. We haven't been harnessing a lot of resources **for** the medical field.
2. We haven't been harnessing a lot of resources **in** the medical field.

Comment: Both are grammatical. They have different meanings. What are you trying to express? Resources in general that are being used in medicine as opposed to something else, or resources specific to medicine that are being used as designed?

Comment: Side note: "a lot" is fairly informal whereas "harnessing" is fairly formal. Consider changing one of them to fit the desired register.

Answer (score 0):

"Resource" can take a complement with "for", specifying the purpose or target of the resource. So *A resource for the medical field* means a resource applied to the medical field, which doesn't make a lot of sense, and would probably be interpreted as *A resource for certain unspecified activities in the medical field*.

"Resource" does not take a complement with "in", so if you use an "in" phrase with it, it is an adjunct, with no special meaning attached to "in". If you say *a resource in the medical field* it means *A resource for something unspecified in the medical field*.

So in this case, there is no difference in meaning that I can find. But if the complement were something that the resource could be directly applied to (eg *a resource for calculating the best graph*) I think "in" would be strange, and imply that there was some (unspecified) part of the calculating that the resource helped with.

Comment: Actually what I mean by resources  are ( money, effort, research,attention,etc).